# Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes. Prove that $p^{q-1} + q^{p-1} =1 \mod pq$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes. Prove that $$p^{q-1} + q^{p-1} =1 \mod pq$$  I try to used Fermat little theorem and I obtain the congruence $p^q +q^p=0 \mod pq$. From this I don know how to relate to the congruence on the question.

Comment: I think Fermat's little theorem states that, if $p\not\mid a,$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p.$ You can apply this to $p$ and $q$, concluding with Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** It is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$, and also modulo $q$. Modulo $p$, the first part is congruent to $0$, and the scond part is congruent to $1$, by Fermat's Theorem.

Answer (score 6):

By Fermat's little theorem $p^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $q^{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod{q}$, now adding these two $$p^{q-1}+q^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{q}$$ Similarly, the above also holds modulo $p$. Now since $\gcd (p,q)=1$, this also holds modulo $pq$.

Comment: U meant now adding these two means congruent to 0mod(q) right ?( Not p)

Comment: Now I goofed! Meant 1modq not zero ! And couldn't edit

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss Yes, thanks; edited.